# Как правильно установить параметры для компиляции LESS?

Tags: less

Возникли проблемы с созданием корректного файла `.map`.
Компилирую таким образом:

```
lessc --source-map=styles.map styles.less styles.css
```

Проблема следующая: путь к источнику записывается верно для локалки; вот начало файла styles.map: `{"version":3,"sources":["C:/xampp/htdocs/Projects/TestSite/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/bower_components/bootstrap/less/normalize.less" ...`
После закачивания на сервер все маршруты в `.map` воспринимаются некорректно. Если заменить все `C:/xampp/htdocs/Projects/TestSite` на пустую строку, все становится на свои места.
Какие параметры нужно записать, чтобы файл `.map` создался как нужно? (И еще вопрос: поискал в сети - ничего не нашел; значит люди с такой проблемой обычно не сталкиваются. Отсюда вопрос: что я делаю не так как все?)

Пробовал использовать директиву `--source-map-less-inline`. Она записывает содержание всех файлов `.less` внутрь файла `.map`. Все работает исправно. Но файл `.map` очень сильно при этом раздувается (это неудобно, поскольку он часто закачивается на сервер).

Comment: Попробуйте опцию `--relative-urls`

Comment: Нет. Не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На общем [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458056/compiling-less-with-mapping-how-to-set-relative-path-for-sources) помогли:
нужно использовать [--source-map-basepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458056/compiling-less-with-mapping-how-to-set-relative-path-for-sources)
 Таким образом можно стереть ненужную часть пути.
Спасибо  [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) (кстати человек из Москвы, но, к сожалению, общается только на общем SO)